# Firefox and Codeblocks problems

Tags: firefox, code-blocks

Ubuntu is constantly crashing with programs like Codeblocks and Firefox.

With Firefox it just goes slightly dark and after 6-7 seconds it's running again. But in code-blocks it just crashes.

I tried reinstalling Codeblocks but it didn't work.

Comment: Does Ubuntu Crashes Only when you are opening Firefox or when on start up ?

Comment: On startup, While opening firefox and when opening codeblocks.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any open bugs that relate to your problem for that program? As for Firefox greying out and then coming back, that means that the program wasn't responding. You probably had too much running for the amount of memory you had available. Happens to me all the time as I have an old computer with less than a GB of RAM.

Comment: @TamimAdDari: Take a look at <a href="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/codeblocks/+bug/1176508">this</a> bug and see if it is related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could *not* get codeblocks to work in Ubuntu saucy

In the end I found a repository that solved it here (latest post)
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/codeblocks/+bug/1176508

- apt-get --purge remove codeblocks*
- added those 4 lines to my sources.list,
- apt-get update
- apt-get install codeblocks*

It will install some stuff from normal ubuntu repositories and the codeblocks-specific packages from there (it said raring, rev 9295 when I did it).

This works for me, hope it helps others